# AWS SDK S3 V3 Client in NodeJS in Docker : "The specified key does not exist"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, nestjs

This problem is driving me mad for 2 days now.

I am trying to run a NodeJS (NestJS) application in a Docker Container.
The application does some things with AWS SDK S3 (v3).

#### Code

To get the Client I use the following code:

```
private client = new S3Client({
    credentials: fromIni({
          profile: 'default',
          filepath: '~/.aws/credentials',
          configFilepath: '~/.aws/config',
        }),
    region: this.bucketRegion,
});
```

Then I try to get all S3 objects:

```
const command = new ListObjectsCommand({
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/naming-convention
  Bucket: CONSTANTS.FILES.S3.BUCKET,
});
const filesInS3Response = await this.client.send(command);
const filesInS3 = filesInS3Response.Contents;
```

#### Error Message

When I start the Docker Container, and query this endpoint, I get the following error in docker-compose logs:

```
[Nest] 1  - 02/16/2023, 11:40:15 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] The specified key does not exist.
NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.
     at deserializeAws_restXmlNoSuchKeyResponse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_restXml.js:6155:23)
     at deserializeAws_restXmlGetObjectAttributesCommandError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_restXml.js:4450:25)
     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
     at async /usr/src/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/deserializerMiddleware.js:7:24
     at async /usr/src/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-cjs/middleware.js:14:20
     at async /usr/src/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/retryMiddleware.js:27:46
     at async /usr/src/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:5:22
     at async AdminS3FilesService.showS3Files (/usr/src/app/dist/src/admin/admin_s3files.service.js:57:37)
```

#### Dockerfile

The relevant part from the Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir -p /root/.aws
COPY --from=builder /root/.aws/credentials /root/.aws/credentials
COPY --from=builder /root/.aws/config /root/.aws/config
RUN ls -la /root/.aws
RUN whoami
```

And when I look in the running Container, there is indeed a credentials and config file in the ~/.aws directory.

They look like:
(Credentials)

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIA3UHGDIBNT3MSM2WN
aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And config:

```
[profile default]
region=eu-central-1
```

#### Full code (NestJS)

```js
@Injectable()
export class AdminS3FilesService {
  constructor(
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
    private filesService: FilesService,
  ) {}

  private readonly logger = new Logger(AdminS3FilesService.name);
  private bucketRegion = this.configService.get('AWS_S3_REGION');

  private client = new S3Client({
    credentials: fromIni({
      profile: 'default',
      filepath: '~/.aws/credentials',
      configFilepath: '~/.aws/config',
    }),
    region: this.bucketRegion,
  });

  async showS3Objects(): Promise<any> {
    this.logger.log(
      `In showS3Objects with bucket [${CONSTANTS.FILES.S3.BUCKET}]`,
    );
    const messages: any[] = [];

    const command = new ListObjectsCommand({
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/naming-convention
      Bucket: CONSTANTS.FILES.S3.BUCKET,
    });
    const filesInS3Response = await this.client.send(command);
    const filesInS3 = filesInS3Response.Contents;

    for (const f of filesInS3) {
      messages.push(
        `Bucket = ${CONSTANTS.FILES.S3.BUCKET}; Key = ${f.Key}; Size = ${f.Size}`,
      );
    }

    return {
      messages: messages,
    }; // <-- This is line 57 in the code
  }
}
```

I've tried many different things, like naming the profile (into something else than 'default'), leaving out the config file, leaving out the filepath in the code (since ~/.aws/credentials is the default).
But no luck with any of that.

- What am I doing wrong here?
- Does anybody have AWS SDK S3 V3 running in a Docker Container (NodeJS/NestJS) and how did you do the credentials?

Hope somebody can help me.

### Solution

Thanks to Frank I've found the solution:

- Just ignore all that FromINI method and specify the keys in the call to S3Client.

The method of specifying the keys in the call was not in the docs (at least, I haven't found it in the V3 docs)

Code :

```
  private client = new S3Client({
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: this.configService.get('AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
      secretAccessKey: this.configService.get('AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    },
    region: this.bucketRegion,
  });
```

Comment: Is there any chance that `ListObjectsCommand` expects a `Key` property, and so since `Key` is implicitly `undefined`, the client cannot find any objects by the key `"undefined"`?

Comment: ListObjectsCommand returns all Keys.

Comment: Okay, could you say please what happens at line 57 of `admin_s3files.service.js`?

Comment: Added the file to the question

Comment: I needed only the instruction(s) on line 57. Asking the whole file (more so, without line numbers and import statements) is hardly helpful.

Comment: @Parzh, sorry for that. I have highlighted line 57 in the code. But I think you need context, because line 57 was the closing bracket :-)

Comment: Well, it obviously doesn't throw, which means that the error stack is broken or outdated.